# "I was one for two"

Tags: phrases, idioms

The following dialogue snippet comes from True Blood. A man comes onto a woman with a pickup line, and she replies:
"Okay, that was a good line."
"Well, I only used it on two other women before you."
"Really? And how'd it go with them?"
"I was one for two."

That last line is what puzzles me. Is it a real expression, or have I misheard the line?

Comment: +1 because I think this was a good question. The idiom isn't anywhere! But I found the script, you didn't mishear the line. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"One for two" means someone had one success for two tries. It comes from sports, originally baseball, in which a player would be said to be "one for two" if he had two at-bats but only got one hit.

Comment: I don't know about _originally_ from baseball, but that's certainly where it's most commonly heard.

Comment: I just came across this expression in a standup comic stint and did not fully understand the punchline. Found the meaning, your answer, by Googling :)